# Java and Python return different values when converting the hexadecimal to long

Tags: python, java

I noticed this difference when comparing xxhash implementations in both Python and Java languages. Calculated hashes by xxhash library is the same as hexadecimal string, but they are different when I try to get calculated hash as an integer(or long) value.

I am sure that this is some kind of "endian" problem but I couldn't find how to get the same integer values for both languages.

Any ideas how and why this is happening?

**Java Code:**

```
String hexString = "d24ec4f1a98c6e5b";
System.out.println(new BigInteger(hexString,16).longValue());
// printed value -> -3292477735350538661
```

**Python Code:**

```
hexString = "d24ec4f1a98c6e5b"
print(int(hexString, 16))
# printed value -> 15154266338359012955
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You converted the BigInteger to long which is the reason for the difference. Because long is a signed 64-bits integer it overflows to a negative. If you just print the BigInteger as it is it gives the same result.

```
      System.out.println(new BigInteger(hexString,16));
# 15154266338359012955
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The result is too big to fit in a long, and overflows. From the docs of [BigInteger.longValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue--):

> Converts this BigInteger to a long. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

Comment: *The result is too big to fit in a long, and overflows.* Not really. It isn't too big and it doesn't overflow. The value passed to be parsed is a 64-bit value and `long` is a 64-bit type. Overflow occurs when the value to be parsed is >= 65 bits. The fact is that `long` is a *signed* type and the sign bit is set in the value. You *might just* say it overflows `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I am entirely comfortable calling that an overflow of a `long`.

Comment: @g00se the value **is** too big. `Long.MAX_VALUE` in hex is `7fffffffffffffff`, which is smaller than `d24ec4f1a98c6e5b`.

Comment: @RobSpoor - that's what I said in my last sentence
`byte[] a = { 0x01, 0x02, (byte)0xFF };` which of those values overflows?

Comment: @g00se May i get some source to read on the topic? I have always been under the impression that going above `Long.MAX_VALUE` is an overflow, regardless of the bits of the result.

Comment: @Chaosfire I guess the Language Spec would be the final arbiter. If it doesn't back me, that's not going to stop the way I 'look at it' ;) (though I'd bow to the terminology)

Comment: Note that since the value does fit in 64 bits, you could also print the desired value with `System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(new BigInteger(hexString, 16).longValue()));`

Comment: @g00se I was asking for source out of an academic curiosity about the exact definition :) In practice, I would still consider it an overflow, regardless :)

Comment: I did a search on keyword 'overflow' in the Language Spec but found nothing. Doesn't mean it's not covered of course. How would you answer the question I posed in my comment?

Comment: I didn't find anything in the jls either. About the question, `0xFF` is 255 in decimal, it goes beyond max value, so i would consider that an overflow. Still, it fits in 8-bit, so it's possible to get the correct value as an int using `Byte.toUnsignedInt()`.